# Wizards size consistency across application

Tags: desktop-application, wizard

Is there a general guidline how to solve a consistency of Wizard forms accross a desktop application? I am especialy interrested in to the size of windows. Should be all the wizards of same size? Is it ok to have any wizard with different size? How you solve it in your software?

Thank you for any hint or info.

Answer (score 0):

There are some factors to take into consideration when you the design of wizard window sizes in desktop applications.

In terms of consistency we might talk about the x,y position of the window as well as whether it is centred across the screen or not. It helps to reduce the amount of shift in the focus of the users when they know that the window will appear in a certain position.

However, you need to balance this with the amount of content to be displayed in each step or task of a wizard window. the trade-off is between the number of steps (and how logical it is to split them up or combine them) with the size of the window used to display the information.

There is no right or wrong answers here, but you can certainly use metrics to measure how quickly or easily users can get through all the steps, and how accurately the information is entered into the form. This will ultimately guide you towards the right combination of size, position and contend density for the design.

Answer (score 0):

Design consistency is an important aspect of user experience (UX). When users encounter consistent elements and behaviors across an application, they can predict how things will work, leading to an enhanced user experience. Here's a general guideline for maintaining consistency in wizard forms across desktop applications, focusing especially on window sizes:

**Default to Uniformity**: As a general rule, all wizard windows should be of the same size. This provides a consistent look and feel across the application and ensures users are not distracted by changing window sizes, which can be jarring.

**Exceptions are Okay, but Justify Them**: There might be scenarios where a different window size is necessary due to the amount or type of content. If a window must be larger (or smaller) to accommodate specific content without overwhelming the user or introducing unnecessary scrolling, it's okay to adjust. However, ensure that the reasons are valid and not just stylistic choices.

**Transition Smoothly**: If you must change sizes, make sure the transition is smooth. A sudden jump from a small to a large window (or vice versa) can be jarring to users. Implement animations or transitional effects that resize the window smoothly.

**Positioning Matters**: If wizard window sizes are changing, consider the position of the window on the screen. For instance, if a window grows in size, it might be best to anchor it at the top and let it expand downwards, or anchor it in the center and let it expand outwards. Avoid situations where users have to move their mouse significantly because a 'Next' button jumped due to window resizing.

**Consistent UI Elements**: Even if the sizes are different, ensure that common UI elements (like Next, Back, Cancel buttons) are consistently placed and styled. This builds familiarity and reduces cognitive load.

**Document Design Decisions**: If you decide on certain size standards or variations for specific reasons, document these decisions. This will help other designers or developers who work on the application in the future to understand the rationale behind the choices.